# Apache2.x - Prevent mutli-connection for a same User

Tags: apache

I searched on internet, but I found nothing.
So I hope I will find help and solutions here.

I have a Debian Jessie server up-to-date, with an Apache2.x installed with a lot of usefull modules.
I created an "users" Database to allow only them to acces to a private part of my site.

But some of them share theirs accounts informations, to don't create one !
So, my question is simple : 
I search to limit an user to one connection in the same time (disconnect old connection because I don't have a button to do it).

This is a part of my working ".conf" apache :

```
DBDriver    mysql
DBDParams   "dbname=XXXX user=XXXX pass=XXXX"
DBDMin      4
DBDKeep     8
DBDMax      20
DBDExptime  300

<Location /secretpart>
    AuthType                Basic
    AuthName                "Authentication required"
    AuthBasicProvider       socache dbd
    AuthnCacheProvideFor    dbd
    AuthnCacheContext       my-server
    Require                 valid-user
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery      "SELECT password FROM users WHERE name=%s"
</Location>
```

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: You cannot limit to one connection, since there is no concept of a persistent connection on http level. The protocol is stateless, it defines only requests, but no connection. What you _can_ do is limit the number of sessions a user can open at a time. But that is in your application logic, not on the level of the http protocol and server.

Comment: Hi arkascha, so I can not "limit the number of sessions a user can open at a time" in Apache config but only in my web side ?

Comment: I found some things for "Sessions" and "Apache2.x" like "mod_session" and or "mod_session_dbd", "mod_bw". =)
Link : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_session.html
Link : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_session_dbd.html
Link : https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/sandbox/mod_bw/mod_bw.txt
Is it possible ?

Comment: I use exactly the following sample to protect the private part of my site.
Link : https://websetnet.com/password-protect-directories-mod_authn_dbd-mysql-apache-debian-8/
But one of my users share his user/password on a facebook group, so I want to install/edit/etc. my apache2.x configuration to allow at maximum one simultaneously connection per user.
NB : In addition, I should want know with user use with ip.